# .info-box div missing background color in review

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, review, information-display

I was just doing some LQP review, when I happen upon the post pictured below. There is the normal *"Our system has identified this post as possible spam; please review carefully"* warring, however there is no color in the warning. So at first glance it looks like it is part of the post.

[image: low quality review]

Here is the warning with a background-color added to the `.info-box` div.
[image: same low quality review with background color]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been fixed, probably as part of the [Review queue workflows - Final release](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369013/295232), as can be seen in the screenshot from [this recent bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/379665/295232):

[image]

That yellow banner is also present when the post is not deleted yet.