# Alignment issue in the low quality review post

Tags: bug, design, review, low-quality-posts, deleted-posts

There is an alignment issue in the low quality review post. When a post was deleted already and a user is viewing the review post, the highlighted area for the deleted post is not aligned correctly with the above area.

**Screenshot for reference:**

[image: Alignment issue]

Sample low quality post: https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/83067

Comment: I also wonder why the post content is visible when it was red-flag deleted. Shouldn't the content be hidden like on the main-page?